# missing superblock on encrypted filesystem

Tags: linux, encryption, filesystems, ubuntu-14.04, superblock

I have a hard drive with ubuntu 14 installed. The whole disk is encrypted. My default users home directory is encrypted as well. Lately, after a system crash, I am presented with a busybox (initramfs) on startup. When I chose to start in recovery mode, I can grasp several error messages like " ... Failed to read block at offset xyz ...".

I searched and found this Q&A: [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

I booted from a CD and followed the instructions. However I am only able to do ...

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1
```

... and then continue to check and repair superblocks on */dev/sda1* .

If I try ...

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda2
```

... i get the following error message:

```
dumpe2fs: Attempted to read block from filesystem resulted
in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

*gparted* shows the partitioning and file systems of the drive as follows:

```
partition    file system    size    used    unused    flags
-------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1    ext2           243M    210M    32M       boot
/dev/sda2    extended       465G    -       -         -
  /dev/sda5!!crypt-luks     465G    -       -         -
unallocated  unallocated      1M    -       -         -
```

The warning (!!) at *sda5* says *"Linux Unified Key Setup encryption is not yet supported"*.

If I try ...

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda5
```

... it returns this error message:

```
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Mounting and rw-accessing *sda1* works without error.

Any clues what is the cause and how i can repair, mount and decrypt the filesystem to boot normaly or at least to recover the data?

Answer (score 1):

The given solution has missed some commands that you need to decrypt the file system and access it. Here's the full solution

1. Boot from Ubuntu USB
2. ```
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/rawdevice somename
   ```
3. ```
   sck /dev/mapper/somename
   ```

Get backup superblock:

4. ```
   sudo dumpe2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root | grep superblock
   ```

Fix:

5. ```
   sudo fsck -b 32768 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y
   ```

Verify:

6. ```
   mkdir /a
   ```
7. ```
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /a
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Boot from Ubuntu USB
2. get backup superblock:

   sudo dumpe2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root | grep superblock
3. fix:

   sudo fsck -b 32768 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y
4. verify

   mkdir /a

   sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /a

I used following links as source:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox
>   https://serverfault.com/questions/375090/using-fsck-to-check-and-repair-luks-encrypted-disk